# Create a txt file using batch file in a specific folder

Tags: batch-file, directory, creation

I am trying to create a batch file which will create a text file in a specific folder. I am able to create a text file on my desktop, but I need to create a file in a specific file path.

For example in `D:/Testing`  folder I wants to create a user defined text file.

```
@echo off

echo .>> dblank.txt
```

I am using the above code to create a `.txt` file on my desktop.

I know this is a simple question but I searched google and have not found any good solution that could helpful to me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have it almost done. Just explicitly say where to create the file

```
@echo off
  echo.>"d:\testing\dblank.txt"
```

This creates a file containing a blank line (CR + LF = 2 bytes).

If you want the file empty (0 bytes)

```
@echo off
  break>"d:\testing\dblank.txt"
```

Comment: Oho its working fine. last time i have not created that testing folder in my D drive. that why it was not working. Thanks a ton

Comment: how would you avoid hardcoding the path?

Comment: @m4l490n, not hardcoding it (sorry if it seems a joke, it is not). Question is about a specific folder, where do you want the file to be created?

Answer (score 17):

This code written above worked for me as well. Although, you can use the code I am writing here:

```
@echo off

@echo>"d:\testing\dblank.txt"
```

If you want to write some text to dblank.txt then add the following line in the end of your code

```
@echo Writing text to dblank.txt> dblank.txt
```

Comment: If you need to write to the same file that you have been created you should use @echo Writing text to dblank.txt> d:\testing\dblank.txt

Answer (score 4):

Changed the set to remove % as that will write to text file as Echo on or off

```
echo off
title Custom Text File
cls
set /p txt=What do you want it to say? ; 
echo %txt% > "D:\Testing\dblank.txt"
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
cd %localhost%
```

to set the directory to the folder the batch file was opened from. Your script would look like this:

```
@echo off
cd %localhost%
echo .> dblank.txt
```

Make sure you set the directory **before** you use the command to create the text file.